# regex between some character

Tags: python, regex

input:

```
[1] string1 [2] string 2[3]string3 [5]string4
```

output:

```
string1
string 2
string 4
```

how to resolve the case as "input" and the result "output" with "regex" python?

Comment: Seems unclear for me.

Comment: Why is `string3` not in output?

Comment: do you want the output to be string1, string2, string4 with no space?

Answer (score 0):

Your instructions are a bit vague, that said - using the example input you provided:

```
import re
line = '[1] string1 [2] string 2[3]string3 [5]string4'
matches = re.match(r'\[1\] (.*?)\[2\] (.*?)\[3\](.*?)\[5\](.*)', line)

print matches.group(1) # prints string1
print matches.group(2) # prints string 2
print matches.group(3) # prints string3 
print matches.group(4) # prints string4
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't want the value of an index if it is preceded by a character other than white space or a starting anchor ,

```
>>> s = "[1] string1 [2] string 2[3]string3 [5]string4"
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.findall(r'(?<= |^)\[\d+\]\s*([^\[]*)', s)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
string1 
string 2
string4
```